# Error while Working with US-100 on Raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, pwm

I wrote the following code for my US-100 ultrasonic distance measurement sensor. But I am getting junk results everytime. when ever I am moving my sensor, I dont get any change in reading. Also, when I am connecting GND and VCC to sensor, input stops generating. Need help with Circuit diagram for connecting US-100 to Raspberry pi 3 and errors in this code which lead to junk results

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import logging

LOG_FILENAME='US_100.log'
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',filename='US_100', 
level=logging.DEBUG)


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
TRIG = 23
ECHO = 24
GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)
while True:
    GPIO.output(TRIG,False)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print("Waiting for sensor to settle")
    GPIO.output(TRIG,True)
    time.sleep(0.0001)
    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
    pulse_start=time.time()
    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 0:
        pulse_start = time.time()
    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 1:
        pulse_end = time.time()
    pulse_duration = (pulse_end-pulse_start)
    print("Pulse duration =%1f " %pulse_duration)
    distance = (pulse_duration*343/2)
    if distance >0.5 and distance <400:
        print("Distance = %1f" %distance)
    else:
        print("Out of Range")
logging.debug(distance)
```

Image of results which I am getting even though the object is 15-20cm apart.

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwrNh.png)